# How do I know what ESx specification a feature belongs to?

Tags: javascript

I am reviewing an old codebase which was ES5 although I am cleaning it up so that the minimum supported version is ES2015. Having reviewed the libraries, there are many polyfills included from `core-js` which I need to detangle.

How do I find out what features belong to what specification so that I may know what polyfills are outside of my target specification?

For example, straight away there is one for `Array.includes`.

By referencing the [MDN docs for Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), I find a link to the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.includes) however the specification seems to be a full `ES2022` document and looking at the link, I am unsure at what point `includes` was added.  <strike>In this case I know it is `ES2015`</strike> however, looking at the significant list of polyfills, I will not know that for all entries that are being polyfilled.

**How can I tell what's in ES2015 rather than what's in ES2016 and above?**

Comment: MDN used to list when features were added. For some reason they stopped doing that and removed the information. I do think that was a mistake as it's a useful reference to have.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/sudheerj/ECMAScript-features
Array includes is actually from ES7/ES2016

Comment: MDN contributor and reviewer here. This request has come in in the issue tracker, but it’s never been clear that MDN is the best place to maintain the information. Related MDN data is not about tracking spec compatibility about tracking *browser* version compatibility — which is what web developers need to rely on when trying to make choices about what JS features to and which to skip (based on what versions of older browsers they need/want to support in their apps/sites). Browsers don’t implement specific versions of the ES spec; instead they specific features, regardless of spec version.

Comment: All that said (in my other comment), there clearly are good use cases for having ES spec-version info for features. One of the clearest cases is for linters that can be configured with a ES spec version number, to affect what the linter reports on. For having some authoritative feature-by-spec-version source like that, I think the best place to lobby is with TC39 directly. https://github.com/tc39/ecma262 That’s where the repo with the raw data is. And we wouldn’t need to wait for them to do the work; a contributor could put together a PR that annotates the spec itself with the feature history.

Comment: @sideshowbarker "*it’s never been clear that MDN is the best place to maintain the information. Related MDN data is not about tracking spec compatibility about tracking browser version compatibility*" That's disappointing. But also, I'm not quite sure I understand - the information *was* there on MDN. It has been removed since. You can see an example in [this web archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170913080702/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) at the bottom it specified the initial spec where the feature was added.

Comment: @VLAZ The information in MDN was never complete nor was it ever audited for accuracy. And some newly-added features didn’t have it all.  And this year we completely re-worked how we were managing the Specifications sections. So the data for the Specifications sections is now maintained in https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data, and added to MDN as part of the page builds (along with the Browser Compatibility tables). For all features (CSS and HTML and APIs too) , we made a very intentional design decision to only reference the latest version of each spec.

Comment: @sideshowbarker yes, and thus lost this information which was, at least to me, useful. Web development has had the reputation of being a "wild west" of technologies, implementations, libraries and all sorts of other things. MDN is a shining beacon of law and order in this world and helped guide me around. Dropping the information about the initial spec brought back some of the wildness back. Sure, perhaps the link to the old spec was less valuable but the information *which* the spec was is definitely had value. Spec-compliance in ESLint/Babel/TS/etc is a good example.

Comment: @VLAZ I recognize well that some people disagree with the choice we made for MDN in this case. But I also recognize that no contributors have stepped forward with a proposal/plan for it. There ’s a real cost to identifying, checking and maintaining the data. It doesn’t come for free. And for the feature-by-spec-version work, nobody’s volunteered to do it. Instead we have suggestions that “somebody” should do the work. But the core MDN team has no cycles for doing it. There’s a lot of other work that’s been much more critical, like the recent work to change all the sources from HTML to Markdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways:

- The [introduction](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-intro) to the editor's draft specification in recent versions has a few paragraphs describing what was added in what release. For example:

  > ES2016 also included support for a new exponentiation operator and adds a new method to Array.prototype called includes.

  *(not the best example because work on ES2016 mostly consisted of process and specification tooling improvements and big things that weren't going to be ready in time for the annual cut-off, so not that much was added to the language for standard library)*
  and

  > ECMAScript 2017 introduced Async Functions, Shared Memory, and Atomics along with smaller language and library enhancements, bug fixes, and editorial updates. Async functions improve the asynchronous programming experience by providing syntax for promise-returning functions. Shared Memory and Atomics introduce a new memory model that allows multi-agent programs to communicate using atomic operations that ensure a well-defined execution order even on parallel CPUs. It also included new static methods on Object: Object.values, Object.entries, and Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors.
- The [finished proposals page](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) tells you what version of the specification finished proposal was added to (or will be added to, in case of ones being added to the next spec snapshot). For example:

  > | Proposal | Author | Champion(s) | TC39 meeting notes | Expected Publication Year |
  > | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  > | `Array.prototype.includes` | Domenic Denicola | Domenic Denicola Rick Waldron | November 2015 | 2016 |
- You can view the ES2015 specification [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/) to know what's in it.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I appreciate you taking the time to write that despite the question being voted closed.  I haven't really poked around in the specification's before and it seems kind of scary but your answer certainly gives me more confidence to proceed.  

Comment: @user1059939 - Glad that helped! Ah, it hadn't been closed yet when I answered. I guess I can see why people voted to close for that close reason, probably mostly your boldfaced bit at the bottom. If you replace that with just "How can I tell what's in ES2015 rather than what's in ES2016 and above?" or similar, to me the question is on-topic. Just FWIW.